# Count 3 tables and check in one of them for existing ID

Tags: mysql, join, count

1st query; both tables contain all `categories_id`s

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
categories c,
categories_description cd 
WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id 
ORDER BY sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

2nd query; this table *maybe* hold a `categories_id`

```
SELECT 
count(*) 
AS total 
FROM 
products_to_categories 
WHERE 
categories_id = "'+ catid +'"'
```

I need a way to row all categories from the first query (to make a list) and to give me a yes/no or 0/1 from the second query in one SQL query.

The result would look like this:

```
categories_id | categories_name | total(*)
    1         |    categorie1   |   21       
    2         |    categorie2   |   0 (if categories_id in  'products_to_categories' does not exist
```

I require it in the following code:

```
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
var db = openDatabase("Oscommerce", "1.0", "Oscommerce Database", dbSize);

var categories={};

var list_str = '';
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM categories c,categories_description cd WHERE c.categories_id = cd.categories_id ORDER BY categories_id', [], function (tx, results) {
        list_str += '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">';
        var len = results.rows.length, i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var r = results.rows.item(i);
            categories[r.categories_id] = r;
        }
        for(key in categories)
        {
            var parent = 0;  
            var value=categories[key];
            catId = value['categories_id'];
            catName = value['categories_name'];
            catImage = value['categories_image'];
            parentId = value['parent_id'];
            if (parentId == parent) 
            {
                list_str += '<li id="'+ catId +'"><a class="parentlink" parentid="'+ parentId +'" catid="'+ catId +'" catname="'+ catName +'"><h3>' + catName + '</h3><p>' + catImage + '</p></a></li>';
                ///i need to do an else around here if the rowed list has products
            }
        }
        list_str += '</ul>';

        $('#parents').html(list_str).find('ul').listview();
    }); 
});
```

The total output should generate something [like this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-count.html) (watch the count bubbles in the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This select should be what you want:

```
SELECT 
 c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, 
 case when aa.total_per_id is null then 0
   else aa.total_per_id 
 end as total
FROM categories as c
   join categories_description as cd on c.categories_id = cd.categories_id
   left join (
    select a.categories_id, 
     count(*) as total_per_id from product_to_categories a
    group by a.categories_id ) as aa on aa.categories_id = c.categories_id
ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.categories_name;
```

Comment: did you now made a virtual table with above query?

Comment: @wHiTeHaT No I didn't know. What is *virtual table*?

Comment: @wHiTeHaT The query is working. But I see that you have accepted the other answer which is also correct.

Comment: Thank you @Panayotis Matsinopoulos , the query didnt worked for me cause you also made mistake with product_to_categories , should be products_to_categories ( i assume piotr took someting of your code couse his first one worked partialy)

Answer (score 1):

Try out something like this:

```
select 
  c.categories_id,
  cd.categories_name,
  count(p2c.categories_id) as total
from
  categories c
  join categories_description cd
    on c.categories_id = cd.categories_id
  left join product_to_categories p2c
    on p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id
  group by 
    c.categories_id, 
    cd.categories_name
  order by c.sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

Comment: Just what I was about to write, except that the first join should be an inner join while the second join needs to be a left join, and you may want to keep the order by clause.

Comment: @Neil Good point, Neil. I indeed forgot about that left join but I of course intended it to be there! Updated my query.

Comment: @Piotr , your query only pulls the categories what holds a product and not all categories

Comment: @wHiTeHaT please use the most recent version of query. As Neil noticed I forgot about left join. Currently left join is added and It pulls all categories.

Comment: it runs..... edit: left join product_to_categories to: left join products_to_categories  i not have privileges to do so

Comment: i have another query like that except it is based on: WHERE c.parent_id="'+ childId +'" how would i incorporate it with that?